# SQL Server Query Optimizer Execution Plan ""Reason for Early Termination of Statement: TimeOut"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Environment: 
Windows 2008 R2, SQL Server 2008 SP1

Problem: 
Table inner Join Query with 9 tables gets "Reason for Early Termination of Statement: TimeOut" in Actual Execution Plan.

Wrong Memory Grant is assigned.

Sorting was done in tempdb instead of ram even there is plenty of ram available.

Performance is slow when sorting is done in tempdb.

To Consider: 
If I Drop, Create, and Drop one of the index from one of the 9 tables, query will get full optimization again and sorting is done in ram with full performance. However, as soon as I modify the query a little bit, it would lose the full optimization again.

Question: 
Has anyone seen that problem before?

Is there any way to get more information on why the "timeout" happening?

What is the Optimizer really doing?

I would consider making a ramdisk for tempdb if there is no solution how to ratify the query optimizer problem. What are the risks to use ramdisk for tempdb?

Things I have tried already:
UPDATE STATS ON {ALL 9 Tables} WITH FULLSCAN

INDEX REBUILD works temporarily like the DROP CREATE DROP action I did above.

Comment: We can better answer this question if you add more more detailed information, such as the Actual Query Plan itself.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your indexes are getting fragmented. This can happen if you are inserting/deleting/updating the 9 tables a lot.

Example te rebuild an index:

```
ALTER INDEX MyIndex ON MyTable REBUILD
```

After some time the inserts/deletes/updates will fragment your indexes again. You can schedule the rebuild to keep performance from degrading. For example see:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180074(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: I actually did the Index Rebuild too. It worked if I keep the query the same, but stop working as soon as I change the query a little bit (like changing order of the conditions in the WHERE clause). Sorry, I put more information in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article that discusses this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2018/10/19/understanding-optimizer-timeout-and-how-complex-queries-can-be-affected-in-sql-server/

> What are the Symptoms?
>
> Here are some of the factors involved:  You have a complex query that
>   involves lots of joined tables (for example, 8 or more tables are
>   joined).

Note that having lots of tables joined together means there are many possible join orders for SQL to consider.

One of the possible solutions is to break up into intermediate queries with temp tables; another is to determine the optimal join order yourself and use hint FORCEORDER.